# set brush value for plotOutput reactively

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any way to change parameters for `plotOutput()` reactively? Let's say I have an input selector, which allows me to choose type of plot (scatter, `'p'` or line plot `'l'`). For the scatter plot I want to set `brush` as `"rowBrush"` and for the line plot I want to make it `"colBrush"` and `direction = "x"`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you create your `plotOutput` on the server side with `renderUI` then you can dynamically change parameters.

Comment: I can't get renderUI and renderPlot working together : (

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Dynamic brush"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("plot_type", "Plot type", c("p", "l"), selected = "p")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("plot_out")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot_out <- renderUI({
    brush <- NULL
    if (input$plot_type == "p") {
      brush <- "rowBrush"
    } else if (input$plot_type == "l") {
      brush <- "colBrush"
    }
    plotOutput("plot", brush=brush)
  })   

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl, type=input$plot_type )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```